# Is this c++ code correct (create reference from enum identifier)?

Tags: c++, enums, reference

Please check the three cases in this code. Are my comments correct?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Test {
    T1 = 0,
    T2,
    T3
};

void f(const int &v)
{
    cout << v << endl;
}

int main() {

    const int &t = T2; // #1: is there reference to temporary int object?
    const int &t1(T1); // #2: same as #1?

    f(T3); // #3: is there creation of temporary int object and passing it by reference?

    return 0;
}
```

Cases #1,#2 are bad code, but needed for understanding.

Comment: When you compile the code the code what does it say?

Comment: Compile without errors. Write "2" to console.

Comment: @AntonLashkov: Yes, your comments appear correct. Is that all you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all three cases a temporary object (an enumerator is converted to an object of type int) is created and is bound to a constant reference  In the first two cases the temporary objects will be alive until the references themselves will be destroyed that is they have the outer block scope of function main. The third temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the function call.

Take into account that in C++ enumerators have type of enumerations where they are declared.

Comment: Shouldn't temporary object `int(T2)` from `const int &t = T2;` destroyed after this line?

Comment: @Anton Lashkov They will be alive while the references themselves will be alive.

Answer (score 0):

Enum identifier behaves like a constant in c++. You can create const references to constants in c++. it is not bad. Probably you would want to use them for compatibility, when passing enum constants to functions with template arguments.

## 2 is same as #1